# Running Opengl program with CLion IDE

Tags: c++, cmake

I know this question has been asked already but the solutions provided really hasn't worked for me.

I want to run my OpenGL program via CLion IDE. I am able to run the same program via the terminal in Ubuntu using

```
$gcc progname.c -lglut -lGL -lGLU
```

but am unable to run the same in CLion

This is my CMakeLists.txt file

[image]

PS: I am using CLion in Ubuntu. Also there is no error in the program.

Comment: I have also done set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-lglut -lGL -lGLU")

Comment: When trying to run, does CLion print any error messages or other output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clion uses CMake for project files, and CMake makes it easy to link libraries that are in the system paths using `target_link_libraries`, which you can use in your case as shown below, which can come *after* the `add_executable` line:

`target_link_libraries(jarvis -lglut -lGL -lGLU)`

The documentation for target_link_libraries is here:
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/target_link_libraries.html

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick

Answer (score 2):

I have made it work in both Windows 10 and Linux (Ubuntu 16.04) after a lot of searching on Google. Apparently it's not so easy to find after all. So, I am gonna put an end to this problem now and here.

Here, I am going to show you how to configure the CMakeLists.txt file to compile a OpenGL program which is the main challenge here. I am assuming that you can write basic OpenGL programs and you have written a file named 
'demoMain.cpp'.

### For Windows

I am assuming you can setup OpenGL on windows. If you can't, there are plenty of tutorials on youtube and StackOverflow. After that, continue.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(Graphics_Offline_1) # Your Project Name

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

include_directories(OpenGL)
include_directories(OpenGL/include) # OpenGL/include has to contain the required OpenGL's .h files
include_directories(OpenGL/lib) # OpenGL/lib has to contain the required OpenGL's .lib files


# glut32.dll must be present in "project-directory/OpenGL/dll/"


add_custom_target(glutdlllib
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/OpenGL/dll/glut32.dll ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
    )

# required .lib files to be copied into compiler's proper directory
set(OpenGlLibs glaux glu32 glui32 glut32 opengl32)


#These 3 lines are just linking and making executables

add_executable(demo demoMain.cpp)

target_link_libraries(demo ${OpenGlLibs})

add_dependencies(demo glutdlllib)
```

### For Linux (Ubuntu 16.04)

It should work for other Ubuntu versions too. Linux has made it easier to use OpenGL than Windows.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10) # common to every CLion project
project(OpenGLLinuxTest) # project name


set(OpenGlLinkers -lglut -lGLU -lGL) # setting all the Glut libraries as one variable.


################################################

add_executable(OpenGLLinuxTest1 main.cpp ) #common to all clion project
target_link_libraries(OpenGLLinuxTest1 ${OpenGlLinkers}) # linking opengl libraries to the project

#################################################
```

I am assuming that you can install OpenGL on Ubuntu. If you are facing problem with that,

> follow this link -
>   http://www.codebind.com/linux-tutorials/install-opengl-ubuntu-linux/ .
>   If this is not working, follow this one -
>   https://gist.github.com/shamiul94/a632f7ab94cf389e08efd7174335df1c